# Orika Generic Collection Custom Mapping

Tags: java, generics, collections, mapping, orika

Orika has support for generic types, but I have trouble getting it to work with generic collections. Since Orika does not support different collection strategies (cumulative, non-cumulative, orphan removal) I need to write a custom mapper to handle my requirements.

The problem is that Orika does not apply this mapper, but instead tries to use the normal collection mapping logic.

```
Type<List<Document>> DOCUMENT_LIST = new TypeBuilder<List<Document>>() {}.build();
Type<List<DocumentRepresentation>> DOCUMENT_REP_LIST = new TypeBuilder<List<DocumentRepresentation>>() {}.build();

mapperFactory.classMap(DOCUMENT_LIST, DOCUMENT_REP_LIST)
                .mapNulls(true)
                .mapNullsInReverse(true)
                .customize(new NonCumulativeListMapperDocumentToDocumentRepresentation())
                .register();

public class NonCumulativeListMapperDocumentToDocumentRepresentation
        extends CustomMapper<List<Document>, List<DocumentRepresentation>> {
    //mapping logic
}
```

I also tried to explicitly setting the type list in the parent mappings

```
.fieldMap("documents", "documents")
.aElementType(Document.class)
.bElementType(DocumentRepresentation.class)
.add()
```

but this was also not picked up.

Any hints as to what I'm missing?

Comment: map `Document` to `DocumentRepresentation` and use `mapAsCollection`?

Comment: @RC I need to have access to both lists and do the mapping from List A to List B by myself. Dozer had `FieldsMappingOptions.collectionStrategy(true, RelationshipType.NON_CUMULATIVE)` whereas Orika only uses addAll from what I've seen. That is why I implemented the logic in a custom mapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done by registering your custom mapper:

```
mapperFactory.registerMapper(new NonCumulativeListMapperDocumentToDocumentRepresentation());
```

And it will be used later when Orika have to map DOCUMENT_LIST DOCUMENT_REP_LIST. The last fieldMap configuration is not needed.

For more information about Merging collections in Orika, please refer to this 
[simple test (CustomMergerTest)](https://github.com/orika-mapper/orika/blob/master/tests/src/main/java/ma/glasnost/orika/test/community/CustomMergerTest.java#L157).

Comment: what is the difference to `mapperFactory.classMap(DOCUMENT_LIST, DOCUMENT_REP_LIST)
                .mapNulls(true)
                .mapNullsInReverse(true)
                .customize(new NonCumulativeListMapperDocumentToDocumentRepresentation())
                .register();`

Comment: When registering a classmap this tell Orika to generate a new Mapper with a customized part (NonCumulativeListMapperDocumentToDocumentRepresentation), but this will remain just a part of the mapping process.

The second one tell Orika to just use the given mapper, and gives you back the hole control over mapping process between the two collections, I guess this is what you need to implement the desired behavior.

Comment: Ok I get it now, but I am wondering why there is no `.mapper()` option like `.converter()` for fieldMap. Or is there another way to restrict the custom mapper only to certain field mappings?

Comment: The idea about Orika if there is something very specific you can always exclude it and handle it by ClassMapBuilder.customize but if there is some real benefits (more than 3 different use cases) it can be added to the API. Just to keep the API simple and minimize confusion. For example even with Mapper vs Converter vs ObjectFactory sometime people get confused and do not know what to use...